# class swap on scroll in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a navbar whichs swaps classes to fade the background in and out.

I've targeted the window itself and listen to the scroll, determining on how far down the user is at the page, if the user if further down than 800px, the navbar should fade out, if the user scrolls back up to the top, the navbar should fade in again

This is what I have:

Javascript:
    
       $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
                $( "#nav" ).removeClass('.menuOut', 500);
                $( "#nav" ).addClass('.menuIn', 500);

```
        } else {
            console.log('there');
            $( "#nav" ).removeClass('.menuIn', 500);
            $( "#nav" ).addClass('.menuOut', 500);

        }
    });
</script>
```

Navbar:

```
<nav id="nav" class="navbar menuIn">
    <!--Content-->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.menuIn {
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,50.3);
}

.menuIn {
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);
}
```

(example of what I mean: http://www.albdifferent.com/)

Comment: remove `.` in `removeClass()` i.e. `removeClass('menuOut', 500);` and similar for `addClass()`, they take classname as a parameter not selector

Comment: thanks man!, though this does not have the smooth transition I want, but I guess I can figure that out myself :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this below code it may help you.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 800) {
        $("#nav").removeClass("menuOut");
        $("#nav").addClass("menuIn");
    } else {
        $("#nav").removeClass("menuIn");
        $("#nav").addClass("menuOut");
    }
});
```